# Fastlane deliver says bundle identifier doesn't exist on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm trying to upload my app to the App Store using `fastlane deliver` but it's telling me that the bundle identifiers in Xcode and iTunesConnect don't match even though they're the exact same. Why is this happening and what can I do to help myself find out why? I understand that I haven't provided much information but I'm not even sure myself where to start looking. Here is the error message thrown:

> Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90054: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."
>   The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

Any ideas as to where to start looking? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you got multiple apps on iTunes Connect? I was having this same problem, but with `pilot`. I've got two apps on iTunes Connect, and for some reason it was trying to upload to the other app.

With pilot you'll get a message saying:

> Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: [appId])

I found that the appId was the wrong one (You can check those ids in iTunes Connect under App Information -> General Information -> Apple ID).

What ended up working for me was specifying the `app_identifier` (your bundle identifier) when running `pilot`.

Comment: Here is an example of adding the bundle ID to your fastfile as @James mentioned:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/#5-examples